# Can I change permission of a folder and move it programmatically using Apps Script (G-Suite)?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace

I want to implement G-Suite within my app and I was wondering if I could change permission of a folder and move it programmatically using Apps Script? I also wonder if I can export files and folders from Google G-Suite from within my app programmatically!

Comment: both are possible. make sure to read this forum guidelines to avoid being offtopic.

Answer (score 0):

[setSharing(accessType, permissionType)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#setsharingaccesstype-permissiontype) from the [Folder Class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#setsharingaccesstype-permissiontype) may be able to help you. There are also other methods related to permission.

**setSharing(accessType, permissionType)**

> Sets which class of users can access the Folder and what permissions
>   those users are granted, besides any individual users who have been
>   explicitly given access.
>
> // Creates a folder that anyone on the Internet can read from and
>   write to. (Domain  // administrators can prohibit this setting for
>   users of a G Suite domain.)  var folder =
>   DriveApp.createFolder('Shared Folder'); 
>   folder.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.ANYONE, DriveApp.Permission.EDIT);

With regard to moving files in a folder in Apps Script, check this [Move Files to Another Folder with Google Scripts](https://ctrlq.org/code/19975-move-file-between-folders) guide.